# Can I avoid iCloud Family sharing if I upgrade to iOS 8?

Tags: ios-appstore, itunes-store, ios

Right now, my family and I share an iCloud account for iTunes and App Store.
It works well, but the new iCloud Family sharing would put a limit to six members.
That would not work for us. I really want to try the iOS 8. But will I be able to set up  my personal iCloud and my shared iCloud account for iTunes and the App Store?

Has anybody tried this? How did you work it out to still be able to used the shared iCloud account?

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded and do not need the option.
The option is not forced upon me.

Under the iCloud settings there is a choice to turn it on.